# How can I put an increment o the shopping cart icon in the action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, shopping-cart

I am working on a shop application in Android. On the action bar there is a shopping cart icon and when the icon is clicked it enters in another fragment that lists all the products in the cart. I want to put an increment in the corner of the icon and every time I add an item to the cart that increment shows how many items I have.

Just like this:

[image]

Is there any way that I can achieve this? I searched on Google but I couldn't find anything. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT: This is the method that adds my items**

```
public boolean findProduct(ProductItem product) {
    if (cartList != null) {
        for (CartItem item : cartList)
            if (item.product.getId() == product.getId()) {
                item.amount++;
                item.setTotalPrice();
                return true;
            }
        cartList.add(new CartItem(product));
    } else cartList.add(new CartItem(product));
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have written already

Comment: are you calling a api when u r adding items to fragment??

Comment: I am also doing same thing. And i am storing locally data right now.@Neha

Comment: I put a method in my question @Gaskoin

Comment: In your project the counter in action bar is title of action bar?

Comment: @Akbar I don't have any counters in the action bar

Comment: I suggest to use a callBack here and whenever your data in fragment entered or remove just do callback to the ActionBar's Activity/Container to change the content

Comment: @Akbar Can you post a sample code? I am pretty new to Android so I don't know exactly what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure about your domain so far, but I can put here a pseudo-code for how can you use call back, Hope it will help you.

Suppose below is the fragment in which you are adding into the cart:

```
public class MyCartFragment extends Fragment{

  private DoSomething myDoSomethingCallBack;// callBack interface
 //Below is your adding/counting function

  public MyCartFragment(DoSomething callback){
    myDoSomethingCallBack = callback;
  }


public boolean findProduct(ProductItem product) {
if (cartList != null) {
    for (CartItem item : cartList)
        if (item.product.getId() == product.getId()) {
            item.amount++;
            item.setTotalPrice();
            return true;
        }
  myDoSomethingCallBack.doPostExecute();
    cartList.add(new CartItem(product));
} else cartList.add(new CartItem(product));
return false;
}


  public interface DoSomething {

    void doPostExecute();
}

}
```

And Suppose Below is the Activity having Action Bar in it.

```
public class MyMainActivity extends Activity implements MyCartFragment.DoSomething{


Main_Method()//could be onCreateView or something else
 {
           //here call your MyCartFragment like this.
           MyCartFragment mFragment=new MyCartFragment(MyMainActivity.this);

 }

 @Override
public void doPostExecute() {
 //Now this method will be called when your **findProduct** method will  done calculating and customize this method according to your domain 
}

  }
```